# Why can't I see the diffs & sources of revisions on this question?

Tags: bug, status-completed

[Offical Twitter iPhone App & Bit.Ly Pro](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10287/offical-twitter-iphone-app-bit-ly-pro)

Going by the revisions on this post, there have been 3 edits with changes to tags.

[image]

However, expanding the revisions shows no change.

[image]
Another weird thing is that there are no links to view the source, in comparison to other questions. Naked eye comparison indicates that the text is same, although with no link to view source it's hard to see if there are any changes

Comment: Also, in an unrelated note that it's extremely hard to note the dropdown arrow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should now be fixed; any "no-op" edit history is no longer retained.

Answer (score 4):

I was testing some tags to see if they had been black listed. (howto/how-to for those wondering.)

As it turns out they weren't blacklisted and so my question was saved with the new tags. I then immediately removed the tag.

Maybe there is a bug of some kind when two edits are saved in such quick succession?

Comment: there are some known bugs here that we are looking at